# Why android xml file name must contains only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])?

Tags: android, xml, filenames

I am usually name my file in camelCase (like `tabActive`). But it is not allowed in Android.

Is there any reason why android xml file name must contains only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])?

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > /home/trungdq/.../res/drawable/tab-active.xml: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

Comment: I believe this is a constraint for all bundled resources in Android, also filenames for pictures etc.

Comment: It could have something to do with efficiency. If the internal workings of Android only have to worry about lowercase, it could act as a performance boost for compiling Android Apps. Not sure though.

Comment: To prevent conflicts between case-sensitive and case-insensitive systems. E.g., consider development on a Linux machine versus a Windows machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple: out of xml filenames the `Java constants` get generated. The later have very strict rules about how they may be built

Answer (score -1):

your can think it like this,if xml name support uppercase A-Z,but the program how to  distinguish "Activity_Main_Layout.xml" and "activity_main_layout.xml",when you use the xml file in your code,it's very hard to understand for you.